# vector push_back crashing

Tags: c++, stl

I have following structure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct station {
    std::string id;
    std::string code;
    std::string station_name;
    station(std::vector<std::string> &in) : id(in[0]), code(in[1]), 
                                            station_name(in[2]) {}
    station(): id (""), code (""), station_name(""){}

    bool operator<( const station& rhs ) const {
        return this->station_name < rhs.station_name;   
    }
};
int main(int argc, char **argv) {    
    std::ifstream ifs(argv[1]);
    if ( ifs.peek() == EOF )  {
        exit ( 1 );
    }
    // Read the input file and update the database
    std::string line;
    station prev, current;
    std::set<station> my_set;
    while( ifs.good()&& std::getline(ifs,line) ) {
        std::stringstream  lineStream(line);
        std::string        token;
        std::vector<std::string> input;        
        while(std::getline(lineStream,token,',')) {
            input.push_back(token);
        }
        station st(input);
        my_set.insert(st);

    }
}
```

I am reading a file which has information related to `railway stations` in the following format
`ID,Station Code,Station Name`

I am reading this file line by line and creating a object of `station` and then pushing the same into the `std::set<station>`

It gets crashed after some time, around after reading `21448` line. I have around `403523` lines

What is the problem here.

This program works properly on Linux but not on windows

I get `debug assertion failed`

Comment: You have an error on line 21449.

Comment: It's hard to tell, you should give us minimal example which shows the problem. Anyway, are you sure that the vector passed to your station constructor always have at least 3 elements ?

Comment: Yes, this fails only on windows, on my ubuntu, all lines are getting parsed properly

Comment: Why the over-zealous empty-string constructors? Say `id(), code(), station_name()`.

Comment: My guess is that you have an undefined behavior somewhere and are just unlucky that it did not crash on ubuntu yet. Do you have more details about the crash ? Do you have an error message ? How does your call stack look in the debugger ?

Comment: It could be a problem with line terminators - try unix2dos on the file. Also put a check before calling the constructor to make sure the  in vector has 3 elements.

Comment: @jem updated with complete working example, It does not show me any give me call stack , it just giving me debug assertion failed dialog

Comment: A comment on your constructor: I think passing in a vector like that instead of individual parameters is a *very bad idea*. It gains you nothing and can only cause problems. Use individual parameters instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor that takes an array worries my.

#### Edit

Based on the updated question:

The problem is the constructor that takes a vector.
You are accessing the elements without check if they exist.

So if any line of input is bad (ie not all values are present) then the vector will not be as big as required and result in undefined behavior.

If you change these lines:

```
while(std::getline(lineStream,token,',')) {
            input.push_back(token);
        }
```

Into:

```
std::getline(linestream, id,   ',');
std::getline(linestream, code, ',');
std::getline(linestream, name, ',');
```

Then called the station constructor with these parameters (as would have been nice in OO code). Then you would not have seen the crash. Some error checking would also be nice.

Note:

```
while( ifs.good()&& std::getline(ifs,line) ) {
```

There is no need to check good() here. If the stream is not in a good state then getline() will do nothing. The conversion of the stream (the return value of getline()) to a bool is also checking if the state is the stream is valid for further reading and if not will convert to false (eventually).

```
// This is more idiomatic.
while(std::getline(ifs,line) ) {
```

#### Original

try this:

```
struct station
{
    std::string id;
    std::string code;
    std::string station_name;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, station& data)
    {
        std::string  line;
        std::getline(stream, line);

        std::stringstream  linestream(line);
        std::getline(linestream, data.id, ',');
        std::getline(linestream, data.code, ',');
        std::getline(linestream, data.station_name);

        return stream;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream   file("station.txt");
    std::vector<station>  stations;

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<station>(file),
              std::istream_iterator<station>(),
              std::back_inserter(stations)
             );
}
```

Comment: I think you will find the station on line 21448 does not have name.

Answer (score 2):

This is where it's handy to know some debugging techniques. In the spot where you create a new `station`, I'd put an assertion:

```
assert(station_init_vector.size() >= 3);
```

This makes sure you aren't accessing vector elements that don't exist.

An alternate tool is to use the vector member `at()` instead of the operator `[]`, which does run-time index checking and will throw an exception for out-of-bounds indexing:

```
station(std::vector<std::string> &in) : id(in.at(0)), code(in.at(1)),
                                        station_name(in.at(2)) {}
```

Comment: Given the edit of the question, it's already running into an assertion. Back to the drawing board?

Comment: Isn't at() always checking index, both in release and debug ? Definitely something OP should try anyway.

Comment: @Mark: More specific assertions are almost always useful. Instead of a strange assert crash for some reason internal to std::set, you'd get an assert that clearly states there are not enough vector elements.

Comment: @Jem, it seems I was mistaken - it throws an exception instead of generating an assertion. And you're correct that debug mode doesn't matter. A good link: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/074.htm

Comment: Personally I don't like asserts as they cause different behavior in debug and release code. Especially with things that can go wrong. asserts should be used for things that can't go wrong because if they do there is some fundamental problem: assert(sizeof(int) == 4) is OK (we have made an assumption that if broken is deal breaker). assert(vec.size() > 4) is not a good idea as user input may quite easily render the size not to be 4 (so you loose your check in release code).

Comment: @LokiAstari, good point. Asserts should be used for programming errors and something else (exceptions) for failures resulting from run-time conditions, e.g. a file missing a column. The triggering of an assertion can lead to the discovery of a missing run-time check so I still think it's useful.

Comment: assertions have their place (Maybe I mean I dislike the overuse/inappropriate use of assertions). Checking input from external source is not a place for an assertion, this is the point where we need active checks. Assertions can be used internally to verify pre/post conditions on code that is supposed to be using validated data (mainly to catch bugs in the unit test setup) so we can catch bugs during testing but run fool speed in release.

Comment: @LokiAstari I'm in complete agreement. I wanted to put the assertion at the beginning of the constructor, as that is the pre-condition for that form of the constructor. Unfortunately that would be too late, since the initialization list would already have used invalid data. I suggested the next best thing, which was to move the assert to the caller, without thinking through the implications. P.S. was "fool speed" intentional or a typo for "full speed"? I quite like the phrase either way.

Answer (score 0):

On what platform are your input files created? C++ run-time environment should decide what is the optimal line ending convention for your platform. So there might be some issue with that, but that doesn't explain why does the program wait till 21448 lines to crash.

And your error is not informative enough. Usually when an assertion fails, it shows where it failed. In your case, it seems like it could be failing in std::vector. Try replacing the [] operator with at() in your constructor. It throws an out-of-range exception when you try to access an invalid index.

Lastly, as others have already pointed out, it is not a good idea to pass a vector to a constructor especially, if you only have three arguments. Not only it might produce hard-to-catch bugs, but you are paying the price for an additional constructor and destructor in each iteration of the while loop. Hope it helps.